# Comando git para actualizar un solo archivo

Tags: git, github

Supongamos que con git clone me he descargado el repositorio. Y a medida que va avanzando el proyecto, voy haciendo git pull para descargarme los nuevos archivos.
Pero ahora lo que quiero es actualizar un sólo archivo de uno de los git pull que hice, ya que he hecho cambios en algunos archivos pero en uno en concreto quiero tenerlo como en del remoto.
¿Cómo se hace?

Comment: Primero ejecuta `git fetch --all`. Luego usa `git checkout origin/main -- src/scss/main.scss` donde `src/scss/main.scss` es la ruta al archivo que quieres actualizar desde la raíz de tu proyecto. Checa bien si tu rama principal se llama `master` o se llama `main` antes de ejecutar el comando. Para otras alternativas checa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375418/git-how-to-pull-a-single-file-from-a-server-repository-in-git).

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
git checkout nombreDelArchivo.html
```

Eso dejara el archivo exactamente igual al ultimo commit

Saludos.

Comment: No sería eso. No quiero subir nada al remoto. Quiero tener un archivo exactamente igual a como está en el remoto. Con el último git pull me descargué/actualicé varios archivos y  de todos esos, en uno de ellos, he hecho cambios que quiero revertir, es decir, tenerlo exactamente igual a como está en el remoto.

Comment: Con [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) no subes nada a remoto, tu archivo adquiere la versión que has obtenido tras el `pull`.